# Sidewalk damage

Tags: sidewall-damage

Unfortunately made brutal contact with a curb pulling up to enter my code to get into my storage unit.

Does this look like it'll be okay or I'll need to replace it?

(I'm like 99% sure I'll have to replace)

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyNlH.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyNlH.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL0NX.jpg)[image]